# How to parse html table to json in nodejs with or without 3rd party libraries

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've got the following response from the server which needs to be converted to JSON format in NodeJS with or without additional libraries. I know this topic was touched a few times but couldn't find anything that would match good answer.

```
<table class="sortable table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%">Rank</th>
            <th width="20%">Name</th>
            <th width="30%">Image</th>
            <th width="20%">Country</th>
            <th width="10%">Population</th>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#79ff76">
            <td align="center"><b>1</b></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="/link/Tokyo" title="Tokyo">Tokyo</a></td>
            <td>
                <a href="/img/Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg" class="image">
                    <img alt="Skyscrapers of Shinjuku 2009 January.jpg" src="/img/Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg"
                        width="200" height="200" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td align="center"><a href="/link/Japan" title="Japan">Japan</a></td>
            <td align="center"><b>39,800,000</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#abd5f5">
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td align="center"><a href="/link/Jakarta" title="Jakarta">Jakarta</a></td>
            <td>
                <a href="/img/Jakarta_Car_Free_Day.jpg" class="image">
                    <img alt="Jakarta Car Free Day.jpg" src="/img/Jakarta_Car_Free_Day.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td align="center"><a href="/link/Indonesia" title="Indonesia">Indonesia</a></td>
            <td align="center">28,900,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The output should be like that:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Tokyo",
      "country": "Japan",
      "population": 39800000,
      "url": "link/Tokyo"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jakarta",
      "country": "Indonesia",
      "population": 28900000,
      "url": "link/Jakarta"
    }
]
```

Comment: *"without additional libraries"*: you don't.

Comment: Without something to parse the DOM your looking at using regular expressions or just text comparison.

Comment: Actually it can be with a library that will help parsing that table. The problem is to define which cells are which.

Comment: @PeterM. it can only be done with external libraries to parse the DOM (something like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) for example). Once you have that you can start talking, but not without libs.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Ok. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the position of the data in the table won't change you can use this code. Ideally you should have some id or class to identify the data. If you manage to do that, then change the selectors accordingly.

https://repl.it/@rafaelcastrocouto/Peter-M-Question

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
jsdom.fromFile('table.html').then(function (dom) {
  var tableRows = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  var array = [];
  for (var i=1; i<tableRows.length; i++) {
    var name = tableRows[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent;
    var country = tableRows[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(4)').textContent;
    var pop = tableRows[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(5)').textContent;
    var url = tableRows[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(2) a').href;
    array.push({
      'name': name,
      'country': country,
      'population': pop,
      'url': url
    });
  }
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array)
  console.log(jsonString);
});
```

Comment: It's not from file. It is coming from REST.

Comment: In that case you can change the code to `jsdom.fromURL("https://example.com/")` [read more](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#fromurl)

Answer (score -1):

In Node you can use `new DOMParser().parseFromString('<hi>Hello</hi>','text/html')`, this will return a parsable DOM tree with attributes which you can walk to obtain your Object.